# Глобальный перехват нажатия клавиш клавиатуры (hook)

Tags: c#, winforms, hook, keyboardhook

Не понимаю как объявить вместо клавиши с "d" с параметром Keys, клавишу которую нажимает пользователь во 2-й форме и которая хранится в Storage.cs.

P.S. [HookKeyBoard] - Все связанное с хуком.
Загрузил проект на Яндекс.Диск, кому-то так будет более понятнее: 
https://yadi.sk/d/RNTbfC9kfCXiZw

***Уточняю, что мне нужно сделать. В хуке идет отлов нажатий всех клавиш с модификаторами, и в последствии их регистрация. Мне-же нужно сделать отлов только одной клавиши (пользователь сам её выбирает) с модификаторами (ALT,WIN,SHIFT,CTRL) - эти модификаторы уже написаны, поэтому их трогать не нужно. Но я столкнулся с проблемой регистрации этой клавиши, так как в хуке регистрация на прямую через Keys, а мне нужно сделать эту регистрацию через ту клавишу, которая хранится в классе Storage***

Comment: Надеюсь увидеть хотя-бы примерное решение потому, что по-другому до меня вряд-ли дойдет что-либо

Comment: У нас не принято загружать файлы на Яндекс:диск или другие ресурсы. Цель сайта -- построение базы знаний для многих людей, а не для ответа конкретному человеку. Файлы многие удаляют после ответа, поэтому подобные вопросы резко теряют ценность для базы знаний. Вместо этого лучше приводить в вопросах минимально воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve